# add an item to ListView.builder flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I'm trying to add a header item at the beginning of my list, so here is how I build it using firebase

```
new Expanded(
            child: new StreamBuilder(
                stream: Firestore.instance
                    .collection("users")
                    .document("dana")
                    .collection("Channels")
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return new ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => _buildList(
                        context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
                  );
                }),
          )
```

"_buildList" is just the Widget

```
Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document)
```

so I'm basically lost, I've no idea how to add another Widget as header
any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return the "header" widget (the one you want above the listview but still in it) when the list is on index 0:

```
return new ListView.builder( 
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, 
    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length, 
    itemBuilder: (context, index) { 
        if (index == 0) {
            return someWidget, // return the widget you want as "header" here
        } else {
           return _buildList( context, snapshot.data.documents[index-1]), 
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: it worked but not  whit the `[index+1]` just `[index]`it is a bit problematic

Comment: Don't forget to itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length+1, else the last element of your list will be left out